# Haskell Indentation issue

Tags: haskell, indentation

I am using Visual Studio Code as the text editor of chice 
and the following Haskell code does not compile. Apperently due to indentation or missing parentheses mistake. Since there are no parenthesies I wonder where the problem is

```
safeSqrt :: Either String Doubble -> Either String | Doubble
safeSqrt sx =
     case sx of
         Left str -> Left str
         Right x -> if x < 0
             then Left "Error"
             else Right $ sqrt x
```

The GHCi throws the following error message:

```
Main.hs:51:1: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
   |
51 | safeSqrt sx =    
   | ^
```

Can enybody help

Thanks

Tom

Comment: The type should be `Either String Double`, not with a pipe in between.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is not with the indentation. It is with the type signature. You used a pipe character (`|`) in the signature for `Either`. You should remove that. Furthermore you misspelled <s>`Doubble`</s>. While a double with double *b* is nice, it is unfortunately not the name of a `Double`:

```
safeSqrt :: Either String Double -> Either String Double
safeSqrt sx =
     case sx of
         Left str -> Left str
         Right x -> if x < 0
             then Left "Error"
             else Right $ sqrt x
```

Comment: Interestingly, what does the parser make of the `|`, since it isn't that character itself causing the problem?

Comment: @chepner: I'm not sure either. It might have something to do with the *functional dependencies*, since that is part of the "signature" of a class with functional dependencies. But that is just a guess.

Comment: Yeah, the same grammar rule might apply to type definitions and type annotations, even though `|` doesn't have any meaning (that I'm aware of) in an annotation.

Comment: @chepner My guess is that it looks like a variant of `x | condition1 = value1 | condition2 = value2` except we have a type signature on `x`, e.g. `(x :: Int) | condition = ...`. The OP indentation would add a semicolon in the wrong place as in `(x :: Int) | condition ; x = ...`

Comment: Thanks Willem, Now it has compiled... :-]